# Java: System.getProperty - java and javac version

Tags: java, macos, terminal, command, version

I am quite new to programming but could not find an answer to my question:

I want to write a short code in Java which outputs the Java version as well as the Javac version. This output should be equivalent to the output from the terminal using the "java -version" and "javac -version" command.

With **System.getProperty("java-version")** I am able to get the output as if I use the "javac -version" command directly in the terminal. But I can't find a way to get all the additional informations of the Java version.

Thanks in advance!

Patrick

Comment: try this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-system-properties-key-and-value-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

For to get all properties...

```
    for (Object string : System.getProperties().values()) {
        System.out.println(string);         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version"));
```

Or you can use below code also

```
for(Entry<Object, Object> s:System.getProperties().entrySet())
     {
        System.out.println(s.getKey()+ "  : "+s.getValue()); 
     }
```